# Unit testing for angular directive using date picker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have directive to input date picker, can anyone help me to write the unit test case for this directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
  };
});
```